# Custom WPF ProgressBar To Include Upper Limit Indicator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I would like to make a custom progress bar with upper limit property (this must be different then the maximum value of the control). When you set a value to this property a simple red line appears on the progress bar at the specified location.

Something like this would do it:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can Inherit From ProgressBar class in a new one, add your new DependencyProperty to it of new maximum value.

Set a new style and template for it to show the new line:

https://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Comment: I get this... the problem is that i don't really understand how to draw a line or rectangle or whatever at a specified value on the progress bar.

Comment: When you edit the Template of your new inherited control, you can insert this Rectangle/Border/etc. and set its Margin(or any clever positioning method you can come up with).
We Bind to new property we mentioned before, ActualHeight/ActualWidth of our control, and converter to return the value you need.

Comment: (or any clever positioning method you can come up with), this is what i'm looking for. The clever method -_-

Comment: Thats why I added the tutorial. you edit the Template of your control.
You put a Red rectangle with margin that is binded to both your new property and the actual width of the control and multibinding converter. the logic in the converter should return a thickness relative to the width of the control which should position the rectangle where you need it.

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/328978/introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv